# Switched (halfwave) DC applied to a transformer

Tags: transformer, ac, dc

Someone asked on an online forum what happens if we apply a switched DC voltage to a transformer - thus:

[image: Rough Schematic]

My answer was that a waveform that doesn't reverse the direction of current is not pure AC, it has a DC component, which will cause the ohmic resistance of the transformer coils to rapidly heat up and burn.

Am I wrong?

The context was about whether High voltage transmission lines at 50/60 Hz could be stepped down if the live side was switched DC.

Comment: it depends. Compare the inductivity, the ohmic resistance, the thermal properties, the speed of the squarewave.

Comment: @rep_movsd To see another approach used "back in the day" you can look at the schematic shown in [a youtube video at this point](https://youtu.be/bROZ4hGisgM?t=524). It produces AC at the secondary, should you want that. That said, there's more modern flyback approaches, too. You should become comfortable with both, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *it has a DC component, which will cause the ohmic resistance of the
> transformer coils to rapidly heat up and burn.*

If the applied DC voltage is switching between a **voltage value and 0 volts** then this is what you will see...

- The current will ramp up in the first portion of the first cycle of the switched DC waveform. Let's say it might reach a value of 1 amp (as an example).
- In the 2nd portion of the first cycle, the voltage applied is zero hence, for an ideal transformer, the 1 amp will continue to circulate at 1 amp.
- For the first portion of the next cycle, the current will ramp up from 1 amps to 2 amps.
- In the second portion of the 2nd cycle the current will remain steady at 2 amps.

For each subsequent cycle, the current ramps up by an amp each time: -

[image]

If you then bring winding resistance into the equation, ramp-up of current gets smaller for each cycle and will eventually hit a limit of some value of maximum current. This is with R1 set to 10 Ω: -

[image]

This will usually result in overheating of the winding but, whether it "burns" is impossible to say without real numbers.

If, on the other hand it is a **switch opening and closing** then you may get an almighty back-emf that destroys the switch as the inductor tries to balance its own input voltage to an average value of 0 volts. This can be quenched if there is a load on the transformer secondary.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on DC current value and transformer.

DC current is not limited by inductance but only winding resistance. If the current is not kept to a safe value for the transformer, it can have two effects:

- Overheat the windings, burn the insulation, short it, start a fire. Or just burn the thermal fuse in the transformer, turning it into a paperweight.
- Saturate the core, which reduces its inductance. This allows it to draw even more AC current on top of the DC current, and accelerates overheating.

The usual power transformers are designed for AC only, and for "cost optimization" they operate at the edge of saturation. It is possible to push saturation to a higher current, but that needs a bigger core, so it is heavier and more expensive to make and to ship. Basically, the core will only work as a core up to a certain magnetic flux, so having some DC magnetic flux wastes some of your core (that you paid for) while doing nothing useful.

These tend to strongly dislike any kind of DC current, and will manifest their disagreement with a loud buzz.

Some other transformers are designed to have some DC current, for example tube amps output transformers, or RF transformers that also carry the biasing current for the device powering them. The core can be gapped to make it saturate at higher current, at the cost of less flux concentration, which is a bit less efficient. In this case everything is fine, as long as the current is within acceptable limits.

Then there is the [flyback transformer](https://www.coilcraft.com/en-us/edu/series/a-guide-to-flyback-transformers/).

[image]

It looks like it runs on DC, because the primary has a DC current component. But due to the design, the secondary has an opposite DC current which cancels the DC magnetic field (notice opposing winding polarities) so there is no DC flux in the core, and therefore no problem.

Answer (score 2):

You might be right or wrong- the resulting power dissipation might be acceptable, or not.